# background size: cover doesn't cover the whole screen

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to set up a background-image to cover the whole screen, but it still doesn't cover the whole page, but only the upper part of it.
What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/104215/launch-day-boom_copy.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You're using a URL that doesn't resolve. If I use one that does, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is nothing in the snippet sir

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong URL, this is the correct one:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/104215/launch-day-boom_copy.svg

Comment: body has no height .. give it a height to see the effect

Answer (score -1):

### body { background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/104215/launch-day-boom_copy.svg"); min-height: 100vh; /* You must set a specified height / background-position: center; / Center the image / background-repeat: no-repeat; / Do not repeat the image / background-size: cover; / Resize the background image to cover the entire container */## > Heading ## }

Comment: No. The body element is special cased. A background image applied to it will, by default, apply to the root element instead. There's no need to force a minimum height on it.

Comment: @Quentin there is a need in this case ,because of the no-repeat